# What's the best/safest/most effective way of returning HTML from a Meteor helper?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to return HTML from a helper function after certain logical conditions are met. However, using the `Spacebars.SafeString()` function doesn't seem to be working and I gather that using this method to return HTML is unsafe and is prone to code injection from external sources.

For example, returning this HTML:

```
<object data="/rating/what.svg" width="20" height="20" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Set up like this:

```
Spacebars.SafeString("<object data=" + "/rating/what.svg" + "width='20' height='20' type=" + "image/svg+xml" + "></object>");
```

Can anyone guide me to the best way to return HTML from a helper and how to do such a task? Couldn't find a definitive answer anywhere else.

Comment: Could you not have that code in a template that only renders when a condition is met and has dynamically injected properties? Something like `{{#if condition}}<object data="{{data}}" ... ></object>`{{/if}} this way you don't need to inject html.

Comment: @Shaded Yea, that's how I currently have it set up. But it would be much easier and cleaner if it were possible to do it via just one helper and one if tag. Currently I have 8 conditional if tags in the HTML template. Works fine, but a lot of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if your requirements allow it, don't return HTML at all, just use a template and populate it with a data context, for example:

in your template:

```
<template name="someHtml">
  <object data="/rating/{{dynamicName}}.svg" width="20" height="20" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</template>
```

in the corresponding helper:

```
Template.someHtml.helpers({
  dynamicName: function() {
    return 'what'; // obviously, you generate this with some code
  }
})
```

But, if you truly must use html content to be printed, you can use one of the two most popular sanitization packages, either [djedi:sanitize-html-client](https://atmospherejs.com/djedi/sanitize-html-client) or [vazco:universe-html-purifier](https://atmospherejs.com/vazco/universe-html-purifier)

With the first:

```
cleanHtml = sanitizeHtml(dirtyHtml, {
  allowedTags: [ 'b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a' ],
  allowedAttributes: {
    'a': [ 'href' ]
  }
});
```

and with the latter:

```
cleanHtml = UniHTML.purify(dirtyHtml, {
  withoutTags: ['b', 'img'], 
  noFormatting: true
});
```

And then of course you include the return value of these in your template with either triple braces so that the HTML is not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that `Spacebars.SafeString()` can return unsafe code. Your best bet is to strip out bad tags or injections that you do not want and either use `Spacebars.SafeString()` or triple brace syntax like below:

```
<div>
  {{{htmlHelper}}}
</div>

htmlHelper: function() {
  return "<img src=..."
}
```